# The Matrix Inversion Lemma: the General Case

Tags: matrices, inverse, recursive-algorithms, block-matrices

I find it is hard to understand the application senario of the Matrix Inversion Lemma in non-special cases. Suppose I already computed $A^{-1}$ and want to find $\left(A+UCV \right)^{-1}$. The Matrix Inversion Lemma says

$\left(A+UCV \right)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}U \left(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U \right)^{-1} VA^{-1}$

where $A, U, C$ and V all denote matrices of the correct size. Specifically, $A$ is $n \times n$, $U$ is $n \times k$, $C$ is $k \times k$ and $V$ is $k \times n$.

What I don't understand is: instead of finding the inverse of $A+UCV$, now I need to find the inverse of $C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U$. I can see that when $k < n$, I'm looking for the inverse of a smaller matrix, which may saves me some computation. But in which other condition I can benefit from using this formula?

Answer (score 2):

We have that
\begin{align}
&(A+UCV)
\left(A^{-1}-A^{-1}U(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1}\right)=\\
&=AA^{-1}-AA^{-1}U(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1}+UCVA^{-1}-UCVA^{-1}U(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1} \\
&=I-U(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1}+UCVA^{-1}+U(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1}-UCVA^{-1} \\
&=I
\end{align}
since 
\begin{align}
-UCVA^{-1}U(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1}&=-UC(-C^{-1}+C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1} \\ &=U(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1}--UCVA^{-1}.
\end{align}

Note. The "philosophy" of this formula is that you already know the inverses of $A$ and $C$ and you want to express, using what you know, the inverse of $A+UCV$.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I understand why this formula gives $A + UCV$. My question is in the right hand side of the formula, we still need to compute the inverse of $C^{−1}+VA^{−1}U$, even if we know the inverse of $A$ and $C$. So why do we need to use this formula at all if we still need to compute a matrix inverse?

Comment: Note that $C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U$ is $k\times k$, while $C+UCV$ is $n\times n$. This formula is used in numerical algorithms, in cases $k\ll n$. For examples when $k=1$. Once again, the important thing is that we use the fact the we know $A^{-1}$, and for $k\ll n$, everything else is of secondary difficulty.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your classification. This makes sense. Just one more question. When k=1, we have the special case $(C^{−1}+VA−1U)^{−1}$ reduces to a scalar, which simplifies the computation a lot. When k>1 and k≪n, say k=2 or 3, does it still make sense to use this equation? I think this formula is used to reduce the computation cost of A+UCV using the fact that we already know $A^{−1}$, so that's why I want to make sure calculating the inverse of $C^{−1}+VA^{−1}U$ won't make it worse. Thank you.